# Using fuzzily with more than one field RAILS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

```
Rails 4.2
Ruby 2.1
Fuzzily (0.3.3)
```

I am using the fuzzily gem for searches and it's working. In my controller, I would have something like this:

```
@notes = Note.find_by_fuzzy_description("%#{item}%")
```

the notes table has the following fields:

```
user_id
description
contents
```

What I would like to do is return only the fields where the user_id = 5 (for example). Any idea how to do this with Fuzzily?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in [github open issues](https://github.com/mezis/fuzzily/issues/37) it's well-known requested feature that is not resolved. You can try to test `Note.where(user_id: user_id).find_by_fuzzy_description("%#{item}%")` and look if it works correctly, but I doubt it does.

As workaround  you can try fuzzy search with big limit and then select results that belongs for user and apply standart limit. But it will be slower, so i wouldn't recommend to use it if you have many users.